# How to do MRPP pairwise comparison in R?

Tags: r

I'm new in R and I don't have any idea how to proceed with my analysis. Can anyone provide me a script on how to do MRPP pairwise comparison in R? There is a script to run pairwise perMANOVA in vegan but none for MRPP. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A google search found CRAN package `Blossom`, function `mrpp`.

Comment: Thanks Rui Barradas. However, I prefer to use Vegan package because I can use 'Bray-Curtis' as a distance method. Blossom package only provides 'Euclidean'. I'm totally lost on how to do MRPP pairwise comparison.